# $watchGroup vs $watchCollection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

There're [2 ways to watch a group of variables](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) in Angular. But what's the difference between them?

They both seem to do shallow watches. Are there situations where one is obviously preferable over the other?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`$watchCollection` will shallow watch the properties on a *single object* and notify you if one of them changes.

`$watchGroup` however watches a group of individual watch expressions.

They are not functionally equivalent. `$watchGroup` could be used when you want to watch a multitude of expressions that should all respond to the same callback - these could be individual expressions that target different objects. This could be used for watching `'foo'`, `'foo.bar'`, and `'baz.qux'`. These are 3 different targets - `foo`, `foo`'s `bar` property and `baz`'s `qux` property, but they will all delegate to the same handler.

By contrast, `$watchCollection` will only shallow watch a single object. This makes it better for an object that might change it's properties a lot (for example - our very own `$scope`). In keeping with our rubbish name examples, to achieve the same as above you would only want to watch `foo` and `baz`, but you would be notified of any changes in `foo` and `baz` (as opposed to just being notified for the changes on `foo` itself, `foo.bar` and `baz.qux`.

Comment: wrote a more in depth summary of this: https://medium.com/@jbmilgrom/watch-watchgroup-watchcollection-and-deep-watching-in-angularjs-6390f23508fe

Answer (score 13):

Here's an example of where you'd use each one.

```
$scope.data = ['Abc', 'Bcd', 'Cde', 'Def'];
$scope.$watchCollection('data', function(){...});
// responds to changes within $scope.data
// The following line will trigger the watch function:
$scope.data[0] = 'FOO';
```

-

```
$scope.data = ['Abc', 'Bcd', 'Cde', 'Def'];
$scope.$watchGroup('data', function(){...});
// responds to changes on the properties (or functions, etc.)
// Any angular expression can be used in $scope.data
// The following line will trigger the watch function:
$scope.Abc = 'FOO';
```