# Difference between these watch methods in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem while using a watch, i want to watch an object of array , lets suppose if any of the array from the object changes then watch should be fired so i'm confused about what to use for this purpose.

Can anyone help me to find difference between these two and suggest what to use in this circumstance.

**Scope objects:**

```
$scope.$watch('foo', fn)
$scope.$watch(function() {return $scope.foo}, fn);

$scope.$watchCollection('foo', fn)
$scope.$watchCollection(function() {return $scope.foo}, fn);
```

**Non-scope objects:**

```
$scope.$watch(obj.prop, fn)
$scope.$watch(function() {return obj.prop}, fn)

$scope.$watchCollection(obj.prop, fn)
$scope.$watchCollection(function() {return obj.prop}, fn)
```

Comment: As per docs you should use $watchCollection If you want to function get fired on changing any object inside array.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See "Scope $watch Depths" at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope. Within is a particularly helpful graphic:

[image]

Targeting a `$scope` property that is an 'object with Array properties' (if I understand the question correctly), I've demonstrated a few of the different `$watcher` configurations in the snippet below so that you can see the various behaviours in action.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller("Controller1", ['$scope', Controller1]);

  function Controller1($scope) {
    var _objWithArrayProps = {
        'prop1': [],
        'prop2': [],
        'prop3': []
      },
      _counts = {
        'watchNoObjEquality': -1, //watchers to -1 since they fire once upon initialisation
        'watchPropNoObjEquality': -1,
        'watchObjEquality': -1,
        'watchFunctionNoObjEquality': -1,
        'watchFunctionObjEquality': -1,
        'watchCollection': -1,
        'watchCollectionFunction': -1,
        'clicks': 0
      };

    $scope.data = {
      'objWithArrayProps': _objWithArrayProps,
      'counts': _counts
    };

    $scope.$watch('data.objWithArrayProps', watchNoObjEquality);
    $scope.$watch('data.objWithArrayProps.prop1', watchPropNoObjEquality);
    $scope.$watch('data.objWithArrayProps', watchObjEquality, true);
    $scope.$watch(watchFunction, watchFunctionNoObjEquality);
    $scope.$watch(watchFunction, watchFunctionObjEquality, true);
    $scope.$watchCollection('data.objWithArrayProps', watchCollection);
    $scope.$watchCollection(watchFunction, watchCollectionFunction);

    $scope.addProperty = addProperty;
    $scope.addArrayElements = addArrayElements;
    $scope.modifyProperties = modifyProperties;
    $scope.modifyArrayElements = modifyArrayElements;

    function watchNoObjEquality(newVal, oldVal) {
      _counts.watchNoObjEquality++;
    }

    function watchPropNoObjEquality(newVal, oldVal) {
      _counts.watchPropNoObjEquality++;
    }

    function watchObjEquality(newVal, oldVal) {
      _counts.watchObjEquality++;
    }

    function watchFunction() {
      return _objWithArrayProps; // same as: return $scope.data.objWithArrayProps;
    }

    function watchFunctionNoObjEquality(newVal, oldVal) {
      _counts.watchFunctionNoObjEquality++;
    }

    function watchFunctionObjEquality(newVal, oldVal) {
      _counts.watchFunctionObjEquality++;
    }

    function watchCollection(newVal, oldVal) {
      _counts.watchCollection++;
    }

    function watchCollectionFunction(newVal, oldVal) {
      _counts.watchCollectionFunction++;
    }

    var _propNameNumberSuffix = 4; //for naming properties incrementally
    function addProperty() {
      _counts.clicks++;
      _objWithArrayProps['prop' + _propNameNumberSuffix] = [];
      _propNameNumberSuffix++;
    }

    function addArrayElements() {
      _counts.clicks++;
      for (var prop in _objWithArrayProps) {
        if (_objWithArrayProps.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          _objWithArrayProps[prop].push('x');
        }
      }
    }

    function modifyProperties() {
      _counts.clicks++;
      for (var prop in _objWithArrayProps) {
        if (_objWithArrayProps.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          _objWithArrayProps[prop] = [Math.random()]; //set to a fresh array with a random number in it
        }
      }
    }

    function modifyArrayElements() {
      _counts.clicks++;
      for (var prop in _objWithArrayProps) {
        if (_objWithArrayProps.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          //ensure we have at least one item in array(s)
          if (!_objWithArrayProps[prop].length) {
            _objWithArrayProps[prop].push('x');
          }

          for (var i = 0, iLen = _objWithArrayProps[prop].length; i < iLen; i++) {
            _objWithArrayProps[prop][i] = Math.random().toFixed(4);
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }

})();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial", "sans-serif";
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
pre {
  margin: 0;
}
pre code {
  display: block;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
ul.tab li span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
ul.tab li {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.tab {
  padding: 0;
}
#data,
#counts {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Controller1">
  <h1>Object with Array properties</h1>
  <div id='counts'>
    <strong>Watcher fired count:</strong>
    <ul class="tab">
      <li><span><strong>$watch</strong>('objWithArrayProps', ...) :</span> {{data.counts.watchNoObjEquality}}</li>
      <li><span><strong>$watch</strong>('objWithArrayProps.prop1', ...) :</span> {{data.counts.watchPropNoObjEquality}}</li>
      <li><span><strong>$watch</strong>('objWithArrayProps', ..., true) :</span> {{data.counts.watchObjEquality}}</li>
      <li><span><strong>$watch</strong>(function() {...}, ...) :</span> {{data.counts.watchFunctionNoObjEquality}}</li>
      <li><span><strong>$watch</strong>(function() {...}, ..., true) :</span> {{data.counts.watchFunctionObjEquality}}</li>
      <li><span><strong>$watchCollection</strong>('objWithArrayProps', ...) :</span> {{data.counts.watchCollection}}</li>
      <li><span><strong>$watchCollection</strong>(function() {...}, ...) :</span> {{data.counts.watchCollectionFunction}}</li>
    </ul>
    <strong>Button clicks:</strong> {{data.counts.clicks}}
  </div>
  <div id='data'>
    <pre><code>{{data.objWithArrayProps | json}}</code></pre>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="addProperty()">Add a property</button>
  <button ng-click="addArrayElements()">Add array elements</button>
  <button ng-click="modifyProperties()">Modify properties</button>
  <button ng-click="modifyArrayElements()">Modify array elements</button>
</div>
```

(**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0aqxLAf1bVNpS0mXzkl3?p=preview)** <-- for easier experimentation)

**$watch(..., ..., true)**

As you can see in the snippet, if you want to guarantee you catch *every little change* to a *nested* object/array structure, use `$scope.$watch(..., ..., true)`, where the 3rd parameter causes the watcher to do a deep comparison of every property within your object/arrays. It's relatively heavy to do this, however, so be aware there may be some performance implications on large objects.

**$watch(function(){}, ..., ...)**

The format `$scope.$watch(function() {...}, ...)` actually gives you a lot more flexibility than I've demonstrated in the snippet, however, where I'm basically just returning the object. The return value of your function will be compared against its previous return value (each time a `$digest` runs), so if you want the listener function to trigger you need to be returning a different value at the correct times. Ideally you want this function to be pretty light and simple for performance reasons (it will get executed a lot!), but depending on the data you need to watch you *might* be able to implement a better performing solution than `$scope.$watch(..., ..., true)`.

**$watchCollection(..., ...)**

As you can see in the snippet, this responds only to shallow changes of the collection (whether it's an object or array) - it will notice if a property is added, deleted, moved, and if it contains a basic value like a String, Number, Boolean, etc, it will notice if it changes. However if your collection contains further nested Objects/Arrays, it will not notice changes within them (they're too deep). Thus the need for either of the above two `$watch` implementations.

**ng-event**

If the changes to the model you are interested in are only caused by user input, also remember to consider if you can use `ng-change` or `ng-blur` (etc) events on form controls instead of watchers on the model, as these will most likely be far better performing.

Answer (score 2):

To quote my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220895/watchgroup-vs-watchcollection/30220969#30220969), in which the OP never accepted an answer..

> `$watchCollection` will shallow watch the properties on a *single
>   object* and notify you if one of them changes.
>
> `$watchGroup` however watches a group of individual watch expressions.
>
> They are not functionally equivalent. `$watchGroup` could be used when
>   you want to watch a multitude of expressions that should all respond
>   to the same callback - these could be individual expressions that
>   target different objects. This could be used for watching `'foo'`,
>   `'foo.bar'`, and `'baz.qux'`. These are 3 different targets - `foo`,
>   `foo`'s `bar` property and `baz`'s `qux` property, but they will all
>   delegate to the same handler.
>
> By contrast, `$watchCollection` will only shallow watch a single
>   object. This makes it better for an object that might change it's
>   properties a lot (for example - our very own `$scope`). In keeping
>   with our rubbish name examples, to achieve the same as above you would
>   only want to watch `foo` and `baz`, but you would be notified of any
>   changes in `foo` and `baz` (as opposed to just being notified for the
>   changes on `foo` itself, `foo.bar` and `baz.qux`.

Answer (score 2):

`$watchGroup` provided at 1.3 version of angular.

If you use older version:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return JSON.stringify(array);
}, function() {
});
```

Sure you should add try/catch. About performance: if you need watch so complex data I think this solution will have the same performance. Anyway test test test...

Comment: The sample code above will have a similar behaviour to `$scope.$watch(..., ..., true)`, but doing a string compare against `JSON.stringify` on every digest. When using the `true` param, angular uses a combination of `angular.copy` (to create the value to compare against) and `angular.equals` to detect changes against the new/current value. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` is often faster than `angular.copy`, but `angular.equals` is often faster than string comparing. I would guess that in most cases `$scope.$watch(..., ..., true)` will be fastest, but maybe worth perf testing!